# How do I add the implement buying/selling stocks on my python app?

Tags: python, stock

I'm trying to create a stock trading app using the Alpha Vantage API for python. At this point in time, however, all I can do is get the values of stocks. However, I want to fully implement buying and selling stocks into my python app.

I've tried researching what methods to do but I can't seem to find a straight answer.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: According to [their main site](https://www.alphavantage.co) and the docs of the API, it only provides "realtime and historical _data_ on stocks, forex (FX), and digital/crypto currencies". It doesn't let one buy or sell stocks, so you'd need a different API to do that.

Comment: Are you aware of any APIs that can buy/sell stocks?

Comment: No, I'm not, but Google probably is